# Using 3 threads to read with 1 scanner the content of a file.csv and adding the content in an ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization, java.util.scanner

I'm training with Java and this is the first time that I'm using threads with it. An exercise asked me to read from a .cvs file and as a bonus it's asking me to use 3 threads to read this file and save the information in the same ArrayList<CustomClass>. I should have some kind of problem because every thread must read an unique line from the file.

This file contains this:

```
Clienti
nome,cognome,tipoMezzo,tipoParcheggio,dataOperazione,Operazione
Paolo,Rossi,cabrio,coperto,07/12/2022 09:00,0
Chiara,Bianchi,moto,aperto,07/12/2022 09:01,0
Abbondazio,Addolorata,4x4,aperto,07/12/2022 09:10,0
Agamennone,Agatangelo,moto,coperto,07/12/2022 09:11,0
Aldebrando,Barachisio,berlina,coperto,07/12/2022 09:12,0
Aldighiero,Barbaziano,moto,aperto,07/12/2022 10:01,0
Aldobrando,Bardomiano,moto,coperto,07/12/2022 10:05,0
Angilberto,Barsanufio,cabrio,aperto,07/12/2022 10:06,0
```

```java
public class CarParkingImpl implements CarParking {
    ArrayList<Cliente> lista;
    byte coperto;
    byte aperto;

    public CarParkingImpl(){
        coperto=30;
        aperto =50;
        lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    }


//This function must work with 3 operating Threads that read the same .cvs file and are syncronize to read each one a different line and put the information readed in the ArrayList 'lista'

    @Override
    public void carParkingFromCSV(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        scan.next();
        scan.next();
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String[] clientInfo1 = scan.next().split(",");
            String[] clientInfo2 = scan.next().split(",");
            String[] daySplit = clientInfo1[4].split("/");
            String[] timeSplit = clientInfo2[0].split(":");
            Calendar tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            tempCalendar.set(Integer.parseInt(daySplit[2]),Integer.parseInt(daySplit[1])-1,Integer.parseInt(daySplit[0]),Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]),Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]));
            Cliente tempClient = new Cliente(clientInfo1[0],clientInfo1[1],clientInfo1[2],clientInfo1[3],tempCalendar,Byte.parseByte(clientInfo2[1]));
            try {
                carParkingClient(tempClient);
            }catch (CarParkingIsFullException e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Cliente {
    String name;
    String surname;
    String carType;
    String parkReq;
    Calendar dateOperation;
    Byte parkOperation;

    public Cliente(String name, String surname, String carType, String parkReq, Calendar dateOperation, Byte parkOperation) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.carType = carType;
        this.parkReq = parkReq;
        this.dateOperation = dateOperation;
        this.parkOperation = parkOperation;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = "Clienti.csv";
        String outPath = "Report.txt";

       CarParkingImpl carParking = new CarParkingImpl();
        try {
            carParking.carParkingFromCSV(path);
            carParking.printReport(outPath);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using multiple threads to read from a single file and writing to one and the same array list is a concurrency mishap waiting to happen (at least, if done naively). Are you sure that is your assignment?

Comment: It was not that clear because this is a 'bonus to do' but for what i understood they want me to read on the same file and  pass the info of each line into a shared list then when all the threads finish use another function to print the Result.
sorry for my bad english btw